# MoMa reason "Implement it properly once 4.0 impl details are known"

Tags: .net, mono, moma

We have a couple of commercial .Net 2.0 applications that run just fine on Linux with Mono. For consistency across our product line, we've recently ported all of our projects to .Net 4.0. This introduces some problems under Mono, but nothing insurmountable, I'm sure.

When running our assemblies through [MoMa](http://mono-framework.com/MoMA), since porting to .Net 4.0, we see a large number of "MonoTodo" issues that I don't know how to interprete. **Are these something I can safely ignore?**

*e.g.*, Our MoMa scan report gives:

```
    Calling Method      Method with [MonoTodo]          Reason
    bool MyMethod ()    bool Type.op_Equality (Type, Type)  Implement it properly once 4.0 impl details are known.
```

**What does this reason actually mean?** Presumably, the Equality operator does work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the MoMA definition files are unmaintained and do not reflect recent Mono state - I'm afraid you will have to check the [class library source code](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class) to verify the TODOs yourself.

Or, if you are really using the version of Mono that MoMA compares against - yes, you will have some issues running on 4.0 profile.

Comment: Thanks! Personally, I'm using Mono 2.10.6, but I'm specifically using MoMa as a quick way to highlight problems in Mono 2.8.x (which MoMa does support) because we would ideally like to support that version. To be honest, I don't think we can, but I should prove that rather than guessing!

Comment: Do you have a reference to a bug / task to update the MoMa definitions so we can follow any progress?